# storing multiple values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a two dimensional array:

```
$scores = array(array(),array());
```

I then have a for loop which is runs data from another array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($teams); $i++) {
    $current_team = $teams[$i];
    // some calculations and value stored in a variable named sum.
    $scores($current_team, $sum); // this certainly is wrong.
}
```

**I need to store the `$current team` in array one and the `$sum` in array two within the `$score` array**. I tried to find information about storing multiple values in an array, but could find it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want column 1 to be `$current_team` and column 2 to be `$sum`? Just create a new array on the spot, and use the `$array[]` syntax to add an item:

```
$scores[] = array($current_team, $sum);
```

If you wanted them stored inside the arrays as "rows", however, you would use:

```
$scores[0][] = $current_team;
$scores[1][] = $sum;
```

Comment: If i use this method, will i be able to read it by this: `$scores[0][1]`.

Comment: @Namit: Yes. The first one is what you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scores['0'][] = $current_team;
$scores['1'][] = $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like 
`$scores[] = array('team_name'=>$current_team,'sum'=>$sum);`

or something more like 
`$scores[$current_team] = $sum;`